# Scheduling a backup recovery in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, scheduled-tasks, database-backups, rman

I'm trying to schedule a backup recovery to my oracle 11g Database, I use the above script with the windows task scheduler :

```
rman target/
run
{
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
backup incremental level 0 database plus archivelog delete input;
backup archivelog all delete input;
delete force noprompt obsolete;
backup current controlfile spfile;
alter database open;
}
```

The scheduler started at the specified time, however backup doesn't start. When i excute the backup via : rman it works fine.

========What i got from widows scheduling task===========
[image]

=========What i should get (it's working fine without task scheduling)===
[image]

Obviously, the run script isn't working :

```
run
{
shutdown immediate;
startup mount;
backup incremental level 0 database plus archivelog delete input;
backup archivelog all delete input;
delete force noprompt obsolete;
backup current controlfile spfile;
alter database open;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your scheduled task is running as the proper user?

Comment: The user that runs the scheduled task should be part of ORA_DBA windows group if you want to use windows authentication to connect to the database. Invoking rman target / uses windows authentication.

Comment: Well i'm using the default user, not sysdba. How can i fixe that ? 
What i can't figure out is why it's working when i call the script directly from cmd (as a simple user) but not when using the windows tool for task scheduling ???

Comment: You need to make sure the *windows user* you are running the scheduled task has proper environment and privileges to access RMAN on the database.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you shut down the database? It looks like your database is in archivelog mode.